# Why is there no proper Blu-Ray support?

Tags: vlc, blu-ray

I'm a recent adopter of Linux and so far I am absolutely loving it. I've been using my HTPC as a guinea pig and I am pleasantly surprised at just how easy it has been to get full functionality out of Ubuntu; gaming (albeit with a limited library), DVD playback, streaming. Everything that I could do in Windows I can do on Ubuntu. Except reliable, insert disc and play Blu-Ray playback.

Why are there no solid players with the correct commercial keys for proper BD support? I can get the whole MakeMKV stream to VLC thing to work but it's hardly reliable, properly feature supported (menus) or easy to set going. My daughter can slot a DVD in and have it running automatically? Why not Blu-Rays?

Answer (score 7):

The general consensus is that we do not pay for licenses. Canonical would be liable if it added support for BD without paying for a license. The issue is ALSO the case for DVDs though: the tools you install are not from Canonical but 3rd party. The encryption on DVDs has been cracked a while ago (and that type of media was not meant to have encryption).

(off topic side note: Windows does not have BD playback support either; they too refuse to pay the license. You need to pay for additional 3rd party software (mostly supplied with the hardware where the fee is included when you buy the license for the software) and that software has a limited functionality: BD playback software for W7 does not work on W10; you need a new version (and might need to pay for that))

DVDs used to be a problem before the encryption got cracked. BDs have better security and playback of encrypted BDs is up to how well the encryption can be cracked. BDs are also meant to have encryption so it has been implemented a lot better.

And the need to crack BDs is not there anymore since there are alternatives.

---

One thing that does work is to decode the BD.

From [howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/240487/how-to-play-dvds-and-blu-rays-on-linux/):

> If you need to play a wider variety of Blu-ray discs, there’s another method that people report more success with: you can use [MakeMKV](http://www.makemkv.com/forum2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=224) to decode the Blu-ray and VLC to play it as it’s being decoded.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:heyarje/makemkv-beta
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install makemkv-bin makemkv-oss
```

> MakeMKV will decode the Blu-ray video and stream it to VLC.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but which alternatives do you mean? Or do you say streaming is an alternative to physical media?

Comment: No, not streaming (assuming you watch BDs for the quality ;) ) but downloading is. I have specific interests in watching content and I have yet to not found a BD release if that got released.

Comment: I appreciate the legal implications for Canonical regarding licenses however I'm happy to pay for an application to allow proper BD support (as I did for Windows; couldn't Canonical put pressure on them to release a Linux version?). Sure, I could convert/find downloads of my BD collection but it somewhat defeats the purpose of owning the disks. It takes time and uses massive amounts of HDD space. Linux is a surprisingly refreshing experience however this seems to be a weakness of the OS to me and reinforces the mostly false assumption that Linux doesn't have software parity with Windows.

Comment: @Daiyus sure. So am I. But the issue is that Canonical is the one getting sued (where they need to pay millions they might never get back) and not you and me. And to get that money back they would need to charge a fee for downloading Ubuntu. Never going to happen. We do have software and the libraries to play BDs (VLC does for instance but it requires you(/someone) to supply the encrypted key to play it and we do not have those for most BDs).

Comment: "false assumption that Linux doesn't have software parity with Windows." Who said that? We have near zero support for DirectX for instance and depend on OpenGL so gaming is not for our system as it is now ;-)

Comment: I was thinking more mainstream user software such as internet browsing, streaming, email, office programs, etc. You're right, gaming is quite behind but with Vulkan getting more support even on Windows it could improve. Gaming is really the only massive weakness in using Linux these days (apart from third party BD support).

Comment: Depends. I game on a console and a handheld; not on a notebook ;-)  My notebook does what I want from it: video, audio, internet for my own pleasure, databaseserver, webserver and coding platform for work related.  I never expected to game on Linux anyways so dont see it as a "massive weakness".

Comment: I guess that's where use-case scenarios come into play. I have a gaming/work rig and a HTPC. For me the current lack of gaming support prevents me using Linux as a daily driver on my main PC. I've been wanting to test the waters with Linux for years; trying it on the HTPC was a good move. I love it bar the lack of true commercial BD support. I will keep it on the HTPC as I feel it's a very good fit, plus being able to play Linux native games on my TV is a cool bonus. Just wish one of the third party BD media players for Windows would release a Linux version so my HTPC could be perfect.